# How to get data from videos in asset library?

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, asset-library

I have an asset library in SharePoint 2013 with lots of video files. How can I request the video url (.mp4), preview picture and video title from this library using a JavaScript API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos in an asset library are "hidden" in folders in an otherwise ordinary document library. The name you see in the library is the name of the folder, not the video. As you have probably already found the SharePoint library REST APIs, you just need to add the folder to the path.

See if this helps to find those details: https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/05/sharepoint-2013-asset-library-secrets.html